# Text cursor is jumping between mat-input fields while entering values

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

In an angular 9 project I have a list of numbers. The length is not fixed and can change over the runtime. The numbers should be binded to the value of matInput-fields. Of course, the amount of the input-fields should be equal to the length of the list.

I did it that way:

*ts-file:*

```
public values: number[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    this.values.push(3);
  }
}
```

*html-template:*

```
<span *ngFor="let value of values; index as i">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Value {{i}}:</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="values[i]">
  </mat-form-field>
</span>
```

The problem is, when you enter a value in an input, the value will be changed there and in the next input too. The text cursor also jumps to the next input field.

A demo of this problem can be found here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-swirles-5yzzj

I also tried it with `[value]` instead of `[(ngModel)]` The result is the same.

Can you tell me where my mistakes are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-hill-rtjze) Firstly don't try yo string or int array to bind. You should use object array for this

```
public values = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.values.push({ value: 3 });
    }
  }
```

in html

```
<input
    matInput
    type="number"
    [(ngModel)]="value.value"
    style="border: 1px solid gray;"
/>
```

if you want int array as result then use mapping

```
printValues(): void {
   console.log(this.values.map(x => x.value));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think it doesn't solve the problem. When I did it that way, the binding isn't active anymore. When i print the array in the console after changing some values, all values are have the value 3. See https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-butterfly-se8v3

Comment: Ahh you are trying to bind directly input this is not correct way you need to convert to object array https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-hill-rtjze